# How do I create a branch using git and repo tools while working with android code

Tags: android, git, git-branch, repository

I downloaded the android code from source.android.com. Then I created a new branch from this code:

```
repo start mybranch platform/external/webkit
```

Then I tried to switch to the new branch using :

```
git checkout mybranch
```

which failed with this error message:

> fatal: Not a git repository (or any parent up to mount parent /media)
>   Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not
>   set).

I tried the steps mentioned in the [android link](http://source.android.com/source/version-control.html).

One more problem:  when I use the command

```
repo branch
```

it shows only the branch which I created eailer. How can I switch between the code I have downloaded and the code I have made changes to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The android source consists of several hundred git repositories. The `repo` tool helps maintain all these repositories.

Therefore when you are directly in the root of your android clone, you are not actually in a git repository. You have to enter a sub-directory containing a git repository before you can start using git commands.

For example the `build/` directory is a git repository itself, you can try:

```
$ cd build/
$ git checkout mybranch
```

Which sub-directory you need to enter of cause depends on where you want to modify the android source. :)